# Capacitance of the capacitor in a coilgun

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, coil

A coilgun's electromagnetic field strenght mainly depends on the ampere-turns. If we have two capacitors:

- 1000 μF, 390 V
- 470 μF, 390 V

Which will be stronger and why?

Does the capacitance really affect the coilgun's velocity?

Is the capacitance one of the main factors that affect a coilgun's electromagnetic field strenght and speed?

Comment: More capacitance equals more stored energy. The other consideration is the capacitor’s ESR (equivalent series resistance). If you put a more powerful engine in a car, will it go faster? Most likely.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun *When the projectile nears [the center of the coil] the electromagnet must be switched off, to prevent the projectile from becoming arrested at the center of the electromagnet.* At some point, an increase in capacitance will cause the pulse to be too long and reduce velocity. Modeling the pulse isn't that hard (for me and many others here), but modeling the mechanics is harder. Trial and error is your best bet.

Comment: A good answer is given already, more capacitance means more power, as long as your voltage is high enough, your capacitors ESR is low enough and coil resistance isn't too high(Ohm's law). You have to switch it off when the projectile is at the center of the coil meaning the window of time is quite short, if you add more coils it gets even shorter as the projectile velocity rises, you have to calculate how much energy you can push into the coil before you have to turn it off to figure out how much capacitance you need.